# 'RelationalEventId' does not contain a definition for 'QueryClientEvaluationWarning'

Tags: c#, .net-5, ef-core-3.1

Подскажите пожалуйста чем можно заменить `QueryClientEvaluationWarning`. Как я понял Entity Framework Core 3.0 больше это не поддерживает.

Сама проблема в том, что я решил мигрировать свой проект с .net 3.1 на .net 5. Сделал всё по гайду, вот только возникла проблема с IntegrationTests в роли `RelationalEventId` does not contain a definition for `QueryClientEvaluationWarning`.

```cs
public override void ConfigureDatabase( IServiceCollection services )
{
    string dbName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    services.AddDbContext<ExampleContext>(
    options => options
        .UseInMemoryDatabase( dbName ).ConfigureWarnings( x => x.Throw( RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning ) ) );
}
```

Мой репозиторий: https://github.com/MaxMartST/MSSQLServerMonitoring.git

Подскажите пожалуйста, может я что-то делаю не так или чего-то не понимаю...